problem with automap interpolation after data cleaning
I want to perform spatial data interpolation on the original
grid (as defined by x and y variables) using the automap library (after cleaning the data with the depurate function from the paar library).
After fitting, I get the following warning message:
Warning message:
In sqrt(krige_result$var1.var) : NaNs produced

Any help with this issue is greatly appreciated.
Reproducible example
library(sf)
library(paar)
library(automap)
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)

# paar library instalation
# install.packages("devtools")
# devtools::install_github("PPaccioretti/paar")

data("wheat", package = "paar")
dt_sf <- st_as_sf(wheat, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 32720)

clean_variable <- function(data_sf, var_name) {
  cleaned_data <- depurate(data_sf,
                           y = var_name,
                           toremove = c("edges", "outlier", "inlier"),
                           buffer = -10)
  return(cleaned_data$depurated_data)
}

tg_cleaned <- clean_variable(dt_sf, "Tg")
original_grid <- dt_sf
original_grid_sp <- as(original_grid, "Spatial")

interpolate_tg <- function(cleaned_data, original_grid_sp) {
  cleaned_data_sp <- as(cleaned_data, "Spatial")
  kriging_result <- autoKrige(Tg ~ 1, cleaned_data_sp, new_data = original_grid_sp)
  original_grid_sp@data[["tg_interpol"]] <- kriging_result$krige_output@data$var1.pred
  original_grid_sp@data[["tg_var"]] <- kriging_result$krige_output@data$var1.var
  return(original_grid_sp)
}

final_data <- interpolate_tg(tg_cleaned, original_grid_sp)
final_data_sf <- st_as_sf(final_data)

ggplot(final_data_sf) +
  geom_sf(aes(color = tg_interpol)) +
  scale_color_viridis_c(option = "turbo") +
  ggtitle("spatial distribution of var1.pred") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

ggplot(final_data_sf) +
  geom_sf(aes(color = tg_var)) +
  scale_color_viridis_c(option = "turbo") +
  ggtitle("spatial distribution of var1.var") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))


If you are doing kriging predictions at the exact locations of the input data, the variance at that point is identically zero in theory. You know the exact value of the surface at that point because the data tells you. There is zero point-wise measurement error.
Computationally though, sometimes those zeroes end up as very very small negative numbers, and when square-rooted to get a standard deviation you get an error taking the square root of a negative number. This is what you are getting.
> subset(kriging_result$krige_output, is.na(var1.stdev))
             coordinates var1.pred      var1.var var1.stdev
11   (312432.8, 5800264)  3.671085 -1.387779e-17        NaN
16   (312412.8, 5800274)  3.694282 -2.775558e-17        NaN
17   (312422.8, 5800274)  3.669411 -4.163336e-17        NaN
28   (312442.8, 5800284)  3.627693 -4.163336e-17        NaN
36   (312412.8, 5800294)  3.679696 -4.163336e-17        NaN

Predicting kriging at data locations is therefore a bit pointless.
If you only want to use kriging to fill in the holes produced by the cleaning process, feed all the remaining data points as input, and the hole locations as prediction locations, then merge the two afterwards. Your uncertainty on the data locations should be zero, and the uncertainty at the holes should be positive variance and positive stddev.

Many thanks for your comment and idea how to solve the problem.

Here is the current version of the solution.
Any idea how to improve or correct the code is more than welcome.
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(paar)
library(automap)
library(gstat)
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)

data("wheat", package = "paar")
dt_sf <- st_as_sf(wheat, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 32720)

clean_variable <- function(data_sf, var_name) {
  cleaned_data <- depurate(data_sf,
                           y = var_name,
                           toremove = c("edges", "outlier", "inlier"),
                           buffer = -10)
  return(cleaned_data$depurated_data)
}

# cleaning the data ---
tg_cleaned <- clean_variable(dt_sf, "Tg")

# identifying holes (missing locations after cleaning) ---
holes <- dt_sf[!dt_sf$Tg %in% tg_cleaned$Tg, ]

# kriging function - prediction only at "hole" locations
interpolate_holes <- function(cleaned_data, holes) {
  cleaned_data_sp <- as(cleaned_data, "Spatial")
  holes_sp <- as(holes, "Spatial")
  
  vgm_model <- autofitVariogram(Tg ~ 1, cleaned_data_sp)$var_model
  kriging_result <- krige(Tg ~ 1, cleaned_data_sp, holes_sp, model = vgm_model)
  
  holes_sp@data$Tg_pred <- kriging_result@data$var1.pred
  holes_sp@data$Tg_var <- kriging_result@data$var1.var
  
  return(st_as_sf(holes_sp))
}

# kriging to the holes ---
holes_with_predictions <- interpolate_holes(tg_cleaned, holes)

tg_cleaned_sf <- st_as_sf(tg_cleaned)
tg_cleaned_sf$Tg_pred <- tg_cleaned_sf$Tg
tg_cleaned_sf$Tg_var <- NA
holes_with_predictions$Tg <- NA
holes_with_predictions <- holes_with_predictions[, colnames(tg_cleaned_sf)]
final_data_sf <- rbind(tg_cleaned_sf, holes_with_predictions)

# spatial map ---
ggplot(final_data_sf) +
  geom_sf(aes(color = Tg_pred)) +
  scale_color_viridis_c(option = "turbo") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = 1, hjust = 1, angle = 25))


You should probably explain here what you've done, not just post code.
